# Enable partial match search for a column of html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

I have a html table populated on screen. I have written a piece of working code to filter the table using a comma separated string on a column. For **e.g** - Column Name = ID, 
The example filter string that I gave = 1,2,3,4,6,8,9,90. So it displays only the rows with these ID`s. My JS code is as follows-

```
$(function () {

    $("#filter").click(function () {
        try {
            ids = $("#inputFilter").val();
            if (ids != "") {
                idsArray = ids.split(",");
                $("#my-table tr:gt(0)").hide();
                $.each(idsArray, function (i, v) {
                    $("#my-table tr[data-id=" + v + "]").show();
                })
            } else {
                $("#my-table tr").show();
            }
        }
        catch (error) {
            try {
                $body.removeClass("loading");
            }
            catch (error) {
            }
            alert(error);
        }
    });
});
```

Now I want to enable partial search for ID`s, that means, for e.g as I type 23,45,78,4324,5436,321321 the table should start filtering for partial matches too. How can this be implemented?

Comment: you can use .filter of jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to remove extra spaces then `split(",")` and JQuery selector `[attribute*=”value”]` would be like `$("#my-table tr[data-id*='" + v + "']")` witch select all rows with `data-id`' value has any of search input IDs, try this example:

```js
$(function () {

    $("#filter").click(function () {
        try {
            ids = $("#inputFilter").val();
            if (ids != "") {
                idsArray = ids.replace(/[\n\r\t]/g,"").replace(/\s+/g,"").split(",");
                $("#my-table tr:gt(0)").hide();

            $.each(idsArray, function (i, v) {
             $("#my-table tr[data-id*='" + v + "']").show();
                })
            } else {
                $("#my-table tr").show();
            }
        }
        catch (error) {
            try {
                $body.removeClass("loading");
            }
            catch (error) {
            }
            alert(error);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='inputFilter'>
<button id='filter'>filter</button>

<table id='my-table'>
<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>
<tr data-id="1"><td>1</td><td>Tom 1</td></tr>
<tr data-id="2"><td>2</td><td>John 1</td></tr>
<tr data-id="3"><td>3</td><td>Van 1</td></tr>
<tr data-id="10"><td>10</td><td>Tom 10</td></tr>
<tr data-id="20"><td>20</td><td>John 20</td></tr>
<tr data-id="30"><td>30</td><td>Van 30</td></tr>
<tr data-id="101"><td>101</td><td>Tom 101</td></tr>
<tr data-id="202"><td>202</td><td>John 202</td></tr>
<tr data-id="303"><td>303</td><td>Van 303</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user [.filter(fn)](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function)

```
$(function () {
    $("#filter").click(function () {
        try {
            ids = $("#inputFilter").val();
            if (ids != "") {
                idsArray = ids.split(",");
                $("#my-table tr:gt(0)").hide();
                $.each(idsArray, function (i, v) {
                    $("#my-table tr").filter(function(){
                        //do your filtering, this is an example
                        //and use contains
                        return this.dataset.id.contains(v);
                    }).show();
                })
            } else {
                $("#my-table tr").show();
            }
        }
        catch (error) {
            try {
                $body.removeClass("loading");
            }
            catch (error) {
            }
            alert(error);
        }
    });
});
```

you can also use css selector [**[attribute~="value"]**](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)

```
$("#my-table tr[data-id~=" + v + "]").show();
```

Comment: Hey @Aron! I think the way you used this here won`t work. Anyways thanks a lot for the idea!